# Reorder columns responsively within one row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

How can I reorder columns responsively within one row? I have one page website with 5 sections, each of them has 100% width and height of the screen size.

What I have on desktop in my first section (`A` and `C` contains images  as `background-image`, `B` is div with `h1` element):

```
 ----------------------------------------
|          |                  |          |
|          |                  |          |
|    A     |        B         |     C    |
| col-lg-3 |     col-lg-6     | col-lg-3 |
|          |                  |          |
|          |                  |          |
 ----------------------------------------
```

What I want to have on small screens (smartphones):

```
 -------------
|             |
|      B      |
|             |
 -------------
|      |      |
|      |      |
|   A  |   C  |
|      |      |
|      |      |
 -------------
```

I tried to use bootstrap's `push` and `pull` classes, but they broke my one-page-layout and I want to keep A, B and C within one fullscreen section. Any help appreciated :) Many thanks!

Edit:

Here is some of my HTML:

```
<div class="row section first">
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-6" id="B"><h1>Header</h1></div>
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-3 col-lg-pull-6" id="A"></div>
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-3" id="C"></div>
</div>

<div class="row section second">
  <div>second section content...</div>
</div>
```

...and my CSS snippets:

```
body {
  width: 100vw;
}

.section {
  height: 100vh;
}

#B h1 {
  font-family   : 'Lobster', Impact;
  font-weight   : 400;
  font-size     : 8vw;
  letter-spacing: -4px;
  position      : relative;
  top           : 30%;
  color         : #66678B;
  margin-top    : 300px;
  text-shadow   : 5px 5px rgb(226, 226, 233);
}

div#A {
  background         : url('./img/A.png') no-repeat;
  background-size    : contain;
  background-position: bottom center;
  height             : 100%;
  margin-top         : 25px;
  margin-right       : -75px;
  padding-top        : 5px;
}

div#C {
  background         : url('./img/C.png') no-repeat;
  background-size    : contain;
  background-position: bottom center;
  height             : 100%;
  margin-top         : 25px;
  margin-left        : -75px;
  padding-top        : 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To design this layout, you may try to use *mobile-first methodology*. That is to say, first design the layout in small screen, then the larger with the help of 'pull' and 'push' classes.

In this case, first for the second layout:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12"> B </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6"> A </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6"> C </div>
</div>
```

Then modify it to fit the first layout:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-6"> B </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-3 col-lg-pull-6"> A </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-3"> C </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but my layout is still breaking when I resize browser window. I mean when window width is small, B and A elements are where they should be, but C element is going down to the next section - as I mentioned, A and C are divs with images as background and those images should be next to each other.
I edited my question and provided some code snippets.

Comment: I notice in your css you specified the div's height and width, this may break the bootstrap grid functionality. I recommend you first remove them and see if the layout can work, then tweak the margin or padding using browser's debugger. Here is a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tooWhite/k8pfLwap/7/embedded/result/

Comment: Finally, I have mixed bootstrap grid with CSS media queries and achieved what I wanted to :) Many thanks for all your help :)

Answer (score 3):

`flexbox` can do that

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 10px auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  text-align: center;
}
.a,
.b,
.c {
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  order: 1;
  line-height: 50px;
}
.b {
  flex-grow: 2;
  /* twice as wide */
  flex-basis: 100%;
  background: lightblue;
  order: 0;
  /* move the element to first in line */
}
.a,
.c {
  flex-basis: 50%;
  background: red;
  flex-grow: 0;
}
.c {
  background: lightgreen;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .container {
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-flow: nowrap;
  }
  .a,
  .b,
  .c {
    flex: 1;
    flex-grow: 1;
    order: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="a">A</div>
  <div class="b">B</div>
  <div class="c">C</div>
</div>
```

[**JSfiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/mdcr0yak/)

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="b col-sm-12 col-lg-6 col-lg-push-3">B</div>
    <div class="a col-sm-6 col-lg-3 col-lg-pull-6">A</div>
    <div class="c col-sm-6 col-lg-3">C</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[**fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/64092n1a/embedded/result/).

`a`, `b` and `c` within the `div` class are **not** necessary and used only for demo purposes.